# Resampling Pandas time series data with keeping only valid numbers for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has a list of web pages with summed hourly trraffic by `unix hour`.

Pivoted, it looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| unix hour | 394533 | 394534 | 394535 | 394536 | 394537 | 394538 | 394539 | 394540 | 394541 | 394542 | 394543 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| page      |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 3530765   |   5791 |   6017 |   5302 |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| 3563667   |        |        |        |   3481 |   2840 |   2421 |        |        |        |        |        |
| 3579922   |        |        |        |        |        |        |   1816 |   1947 |   1878 |   2013 |   1718 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Instead of having the time be actually over time, I would like to centralize so that it looks like this:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  hour   |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+
| page    |      |      |      |      |      |
| 3530765 | 5791 | 6017 | 5302 |      |      |
| 3563667 | 3481 | 2840 | 2421 |      |      |
| 3579922 | 1816 | 1947 | 1878 | 2013 | 1718 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Would would be the best way to do this in pandas?

*Note - I realize the hours as columns isn't ideal, but for my full data set i have 7k pages and only over a span of 72 hours, so to me, pages as the index and hours as the columns makes the most sense.

Comment: You don't really care if two page events actually occurred at the same time? like page 3530765 @ 394533 and page 3563667 @ 394536, they didn't occurred at the same time. But in your desired result, they appear to be...

Comment: correct.  the data is pulled around a central point that happens for all pages at point/hour 24.  I am trying to to align all pages around that point.  The full data set is 23 hours prior to and and 48 hours after a certain event takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is stored as `float`:

```
In [191]:

print df.dtypes
 394533     float64
 394534     float64
 394535     float64
 394536     float64
 394537     float64
 394538     float64
 394539     float64
 394540     float64
 394541     float64
 394542     float64
 394543     float64
dtype: object
```

We will just do:

```
In [192]:

print df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(data=x[np.isfinite(x)].values), 1)
            0     1     2     3     4
page                                 
3530765  5791  6017  5302   NaN   NaN
3563667  3481  2840  2421   NaN   NaN
3579922  1816  1947  1878  2013  1718
```

The idea is to get the valid numbers of each rows, put those into `Series`, but without the original `UNIXtime` as index. The index, therefore will become 0,1,2...., if you must you can easily make it into `1,2,3...` by `df2.columns = df2.columns+1`, assuming the result is assigned `df2`.

Comment: this worked! any chance you can elaborate on what you did?

Comment: Sure, certainly. Was typing.

Comment: I have another question related to this, but it is kind of a separate issue, so I will be posting it as another question